# Animation of a progress bar

Tags: javascript, css

I am making a progress bar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Animated Progress Bar</h2>
  <p>The .active class animates the progress bar:</p>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
      40%
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/miduwu/5/edit?html,output)) returns a progress bar as follows:

[image]

However, I don't like the animation (its direction makes people feel holding back). I would prefer something like this (which feels moving forward):

[image]

Does anyone know which class enables that?

Comment: Are you referring to the angle/lean of the line?

Comment: Yes, the angle/lean of the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're after is both changing the angle of the background image and animating the line from left to right. You can do that by adding these two rules:

```
.container .progress-bar.active, .progress.active .progress-bar {
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
.progress-bar.active, .progress.active .progress-bar {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent)
}
```

```css
.container .progress-bar.active,
.progress.active .progress-bar {
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
.progress-bar.active,
.progress.active .progress-bar {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Animated Progress Bar</h2>
    <p>The .active class animates the progress bar:</p>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
        40%
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your solution is what I am after... Do you know how to stop the animation (ie, don't let it move)? I want to stop it once the process is 100% done. Another option is making the whole bar the same color `rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)` once is 100%.

Answer (score 2):

I just copied the line that had the `.progress-bar` style [`bootstrap.css` (on GitHub)](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/10606a73bcbfc6c723d60e2a1069c921afff0d2a/dist/css/bootstrap.css) and reversed the direction.

In other words, just change the `linear-gradient` direction to `-45deg` from what it is now (`45deg`).

Feel free to add other vendor prefixes as well. I only included `-webkit-` for simplicity.

```css
.progress-bar.progress-bar-striped.active {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Animated Progress Bar</h2>
  <p>The .active class animates the progress bar:</p>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
      40%
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that you want?

```css
.progress-bar-striped, .progress-striped .progress-bar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.14902) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.14902) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.14902) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent) !important;
    background-size: 40px 40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Animated Progress Bar</h2>
  <p>The .active class animates the progress bar:</p>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
      40%
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.progress-striped .progress-bar` doesn't match anything.

Comment: i copied this from the chrome developer tool.

Answer (score 0):

Update the `Bootstarp` class `.progress-bar-striped .progress-striped .progress-bar`

```
.progress-bar-striped, .progress-striped .progress-bar {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(134deg,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 25%,transparent 25%,transparent 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 75%,transparent 75%,transparent);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(134deg,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 25%,transparent 25%,transparent 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 75%,transparent 75%,transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(134deg,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 25%,transparent 25%,transparent 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 75%,transparent 75%,transparent);
    -webkit-background-size: 40px 40px;
    background-size: 40px 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@-webkit-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 40px 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 40px 0;
  }
}
@keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 40px 0;
  }
}

.progress-striped .progress-bar,
.progress-bar-striped {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image:         linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
```